# Styling of Cupertino Picker in Flutter

Tags: flutter, layout, picker

I have tried to implement a layout like this using flutter. [image: The desired layout]

I have used the Cupertino Picker Class for that. 
But it just looks not as good as I want it to look. [image: My actual layout]

I have tried to fix it by using the properties, that are listed on the flutter website, but I did not find any better solution. How can I fix this issue or is there even another widget that is better in this case?

My code looks like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return CupertinoPageScaffold(
    navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    ),
    child: Container(
      child: Center(
        child: CupertinoPicker(
      itemExtent: 40,
      diameterRatio: 5,
      offAxisFraction: 10,
      backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
      onSelectedItemChanged: (int index) {
        print(index);
      },
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Tap', style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white)),
        Text('Colorbattle',style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white)),
        Text('Patience',style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white)),
      ],
    ))));
```

}
}

Comment: Did u find an answer to this yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing around your code, I've tried to implement the same behavior. I've observed that changing the values of `diameterRatio` and `offAxisFraction` could change the way your UI look like. In my sample, the values of `diameterRatio` and `offAxisFraction` is `10` and `-1` respectively. Just imagine this kind of roulette:

[image]

`diameterRatio` is the diameter of the cylinder and `offAxisFraction` is the axis where the side of the cylinder is facing. To mimic the example in the picture, set the value of the `offAxisFraction` to a positive value, in the implementation shown below, I've set it to `10`.

[image]

Below is an example of copy the behavior of the UI you're trying to replicate:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          // color: Colors.black54,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(15),
            ),
          ),
          width: 200.0,
          height: 150.0,
          child: Center(
            child: CupertinoPicker(
              itemExtent: 40,
              diameterRatio: 10,
              offAxisFraction: -1,
              backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
              onSelectedItemChanged: (int index) {
                print(index);
              },
              children: <Widget>[
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 40.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Estimate',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 40.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Random',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 40.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Colorbattle',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 40.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Patience',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 40.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Tap',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]